# passing data from textbox in form1 to textbox in opened form2 in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

i have form1 to enter movies details

in this form1 i have a textbox called NVideosGenres

through this textbox i can open the form2 with a space

the form2 contains 5 combobox to let the users choose the genres if there is more then one

when user choose the genres they will be applied to a textbox in the same form like this way

for example i choose from three combobox

action - war - western

so now i have a problem because i know that to pass value i should do this

```
Videos.NVideosGenres.text = me.FinalGenres.text
me.close()
```

when i click on the button the form2 will close but the data don't pass to NVideosGenres in the form1

any help??

Comment: Did you open the second form using ShowDialog()?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do this.  One of the easiest ways would be to create a property on Form2 that holds a reference to your main calling form. Then you can set the values of the textboxes (or whatever) directly from Form2.  This is definitely not the best way to do it, but it certainly is quick and easy.

```
Private Sub btnShowForm2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowForm2.Click
   'Create a new instance of Form2 (called frmDetail in this example).
   Dim frm2 As New frmDetail()
   'Set the MyParentForm property of Form2 to this form.
   frm2.MyParentForm = Me
   'Show the form.
   frm2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Now in Form2, when you click the "OK" button to close the form, you can use the property that references your parent form to set the values directly.

```
' Property to hold a reference to the calling form.
Private mParentForm As frmMain
Public Property MyParentForm() As frmMain
    Get
        Return mParentForm
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As frmMain)
        mParentForm = value
    End Set
End Property

' When I click the OK button, I will store the value of my various textboxes to properties.
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    'Set the value of the Genre textbox on the parent form to the value
    'of the textbox on my current form.
    MyParentForm.txtGenre.Text = txtGenre.Text
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: While it works, this is not the correct Object Oriented way to do it. Now the second form has a knowledge of the internal workings of Form1 and they are coupled together. You will never be free to reuse the functionality of Form2 without dragging around also Form1

Comment: You are absolutely correct Steve.  Just wanted to give him a quick and dirty solution.  Dirty being the operative word here.  :)