# use a control in a different form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm working on a project for school and have some logical errors.
I have 2 different forms: frmOrders and frmCustomers. frmOrders is the main form and when i click a  button here, frmCustomers will show. There is a datagrid named txtTable in frmCustomers.

Now, what i want to do is when I double click a row, some of the info goes in some textboxes in frmOrders then frmCustomers closes. Also, i want the rest of the controls in frmCustomers to be disabled. (I have set the access modifiers for the controls in frmCustomers as public but it does't seem to work.) How do I do that?

Currently this is my code:

```
 public partial class frmOrders : Office2007Form
{
    public frmOrders()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmOrders_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmCustomers c = new frmCustomers();

        c.ShowDialog();
        c.txtAddress.Enabled = false;
        c.txtBday.Enabled = false;
        c.txtContactNo.Enabled = false;
        c.txtFname.Enabled = false;
        c.txtLname.Enabled = false;
        c.txtMI.Enabled = false;
        c.txtSearch.Enabled = false;
        c.btnDelete.Enabled = false;
        c.btnSave.Enabled = false;
        c.btnUpdate.Enabled = false;

    }               
}
```

Comment: When you exit from the ShowDialog above the frmCustomers instance c is invisible and thus no user could touch the controls on that instance. Why do you want to disable them?

Comment: I think you could [find a possible answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770684/passing-data-from-textbox-in-form1-to-textbox-in-opened-form2-in-visual-basic/28770977#28770977) (not the accepted answer though)

Comment: thanks! will look into it to see how it goes.

I want to disable them so the user doesn't make any changes in the contents of the form. The purpose for showing frmCustomers is to take some information from the datagrid and pass it to textboxes in the frmOrders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your buttons, textfields, etc. are private fields in your frmCustomers form code (frmCustomers.Designer.cs), so they cannot be accessed from another form. Either you make your controls public (which I do not suggest) or you add a public method to your form (frmCustomers) that sets the properties and can be accessed from frmOrders.

For example (in your frmCustomers code):

```
public void SetControlsEnabled() 
{
    txtAddress.Enabled = false;
    txtBday.Enabled = false;
    txtContactNo.Enabled = false;
    ...
}
```

But as long as you invoke your form with `ShowDialog()` the code below does not execute because it waits for the form to close (and it returns a DialogResult).

So do it this way

```
frmCustomers c = new frmCustomers();
c.SetControlsEnabled();
c.ShowDialog();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! :) this really helped in the disableing.

Comment: if it helped you, please accept this answer as helpful.

Comment: :) of course. I was just a bit distracted with cleaning up my code here.